# "The server has reached the maximum recovery limit for the application during the processing of your request." Error Message

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Is anyone familiar with the erorr message "The server has reached the maximum recovery limit for the application during the processing of your request."

I'm getting this when running a legacy ASP site on my local machine using IIS 6.  The site was working fine for a couple days, but it's been about a week since I last worked on this site and am just getting the error now.

I did an iisreset and that fixed the issue, but I'm assuming it will return again after a couple days.

I don't see anything of interest in the event log.  Is there any log files I can check out to see why my site seems to be killing IIS after several days?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you think was causing the error. Do you believe it was a component or COM+ call?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know lots about ASP per se, but that message smells of your application failing during processing and being restarted; there is some number of restarts after which the server gives up and refuses to restart it any more.

Does your application do any logging?  Is there any way to get it to emit acore dump or stack trace on failure?